# How do I prevent my stove hood from sucking heat out of my kitchen?

Tags: exhaust-vent, stove

The hood over my stove is sucking the heat out of my kitchen. Is there a cover I can put on and take off to stop this loss of heat?

Answer (score 5):

There should be a vent cover on the outside of the house, at the end of the exhaust with a damper or louvers.  Something like this

[image]

The damper or louvers will be shut when the hood fan is off, preventing air from coming in or going out.

If you don't have a vent cover like this, you should install one. If you already have one, you'll want to inspect it to make sure it's functioning properly.

Comment: They also make in-line dampers that you could install at either end of the vent.

Comment: @BMitch I might be reluctant to install an inline damper on a range hood vent, unless it was installed in an easy to access location.  Cooking may produce grease and grime that may gum up the works, so if you can't easily access the damper to clean it you might find it stuck shut one day.